# Casting items to end of linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct, linked-list

EDIT*(8:14 PM) - Sorry I corrected my code and made this instead a method so it can be more easily understood.

I am not sure how to properly cast a struct when adding to the end of a linked list. Compiling this code gives me an cast warning at the very last line. This may be the reason why the rest of my code does not properly function.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *HEAD = NULL;

node *addNode(int num)
{
    if (HEAD == NULL) {
        HEAD = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        HEAD->next = NULL;
        HEAD->data = num;
    }
    else {
        node *newNode;
        newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->data = num;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        node *iter;
        iter = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        iter = (node *)HEAD;

        while(iter->next != NULL)
            iter = (node *)iter->next;

        iter->next = newNode; //warning : warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
    } 
    return HEAD;
}
```

Comment: And also, you have a memory leak at the very least as you `malloc()` memory for `iter` then assign `HEAD` to it, thus leaking the memory you just `malloc`'d. (And that's ignoring the fact that the above code doesn't match your question. In fact, it doesn't really do aynthing except create the head of a linked list)

Comment: Why do you think casting would be any different at the end of a linked list than anywhere else?

Comment: @user1177044 - please post your actual code, or this question will be closed.

Comment: Why do you have the two types `node` and `wordNode`?  Why do you try to assign a `node*` to `newNode`, which is a `wordNode*`, not a `node*`?  Why do you create both `newNode` and `iter` when adding a single node to the list?

Comment: This line -- `iter = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));` -- serves no purpose other than to leak storage.

Comment: (Try commenting you code.  It can work wonders.)

Comment: still needs to (1) include stdlib.h and (2) breakup you typedef struct into struct node and a typedef.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure to include stdlib.h -- needed to use malloc
- fix all occurance of wordNode to be node -- wordNode is undefined in your program
- create a struct and typedef both named node -- standard trick for self referential structs

and then all your warnings goes away;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;


node *HEAD = NULL;

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;

  if(HEAD == NULL)
    {
      HEAD = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
      HEAD->next = NULL;
      HEAD->data = x;
    }
  else
    {
      node *newNode;
      newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
      newNode->data = y;
      newNode->next = NULL;

      node *iter;
      iter = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
      iter = (node *)HEAD;

      while(iter->next != NULL)
    iter = (node *)iter->next;

      iter->next = newNode; //warning : warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare "next" to be a pointer to "struct node" before the struct is completely defined, so "next" points to an undefined structure. If you change "typedef struct{" to "typedef struct node{", that error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of problems with your code. The first one would be casting the return value of `malloc` and improperly referring to the size of the type for which you want some space to be allocated :

`HEAD = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`

should be replaced by

`HEAD = malloc(sizeof(*HEAD))`

Since the conversion from `void*` to any other type is always defined and implicit in C, you don't get any warnings about a needed cast. Specifying `sizeof(*HEAD)` makes the compiler automatically choose the type of `HEAD` at compile time, thus reducing the needed work should the type ever change.

You should also remember that some compilers don't like anonymous structures (i.e. structures without a name declared). Therefore, the code

```
typedef struct{
int data;
struct node *next;
} node;
```

should be replaced by

```
typedef struct _node {
int data;
struct _node *next;
} node;
```

Which declares a structure called `_node`, typedefed to the type called `node`. And also fixes the circular reference.

On top of all that, you don't need to `malloc` any space for the `iter`.